# Setting position and rotation of second game object based on first

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have four game objects A,B,C and D.

A is fixed and it's position and rotation is known. 
B is moving object which moves around A. B's position and rotation is also known.

C is fixed (placed somewhere near to A but there is no relation between them) and it's position and rotation is known. 
D is moving object which moves around C. However, D's position and rotation is not known.
D's position and rotation needs to be derived as per B's position and rotation values.

So at run time, when B moves around A, similar movement for D shall also happen around C.
If B moves away from A, D shall also move away from C with the same distance (between A and B).
If B rotates around A with some rotation values, D shall also rotate around C with the same rotation values.

Object B rotates only around X and Y axis. Rotation around Z axis is not intended.

With the following code, I am getting wrong movement of D. Sometimes it is as expected, sometimes not.
Where am I doing it wrongly?

Any pointers to this would be really helpful.
Thank you.

```
private float distance;
private float newDistance;
private Quaternion quaternion;
private Quaternion newQuaternion;

void Update()
{
    if (A != null && B != null)
    {
        this.distance = Vector3.Distance(A.transform.position, B.transform.position);
        Vector3 relativePos = A.transform.position - B.transform.position;
        this.quaternion = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);

        CalculateValuesForD();
    }
}

public void CalculateValuesForD()
{
    GameObject tempGameObject = new GameObject();

    Vector3 newPos = C.transform.position - C.transform.forward * distance;

    tempGameObject.transform.position = newPos;

    //tempGameObject.transform.RotateAround(C.transform.position, Vector3.up, this.quaternion.eulerAngles.y);
    //tempGameObject.transform.RotateAround(C.transform.position, Vector3.right, this.quaternion.eulerAngles.x);
    tempGameObject.transform.RotateAround(C.transform.position, C.transform.up, this.quaternion.eulerAngles.y);
    tempGameObject.transform.RotateAround(C.transform.position, C.transform.right, this.quaternion.eulerAngles.x);

    D.transform.position = tempGameObject.transform.position;
    D.transform.rotation = tempGameObject.transform.rotation;

    this.newDistance = Vector3.Distance(C.transform.position, D.transform.position);
    Vector3 relativePos = C.transform.position - D.transform.position ;
    this.newQuaternion = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);

    GameObject.Destroy(tempGameObject);
}
```

Comment: Why is this a problem if the same calculation can be applied to both object A and C? Since A and C are completely identical and only differ in position, isn't the calculation just offset by the difference in position between A and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy everything!!!!

Just make `B` child of `A` and `D` child of `C`

Then you only need to make `transform` local values of `D` equal to `B` in `Update`

```
d.transform.localRotation = b.transform.localRotation;
d.transform.localPosition = b.transform.localPosition ;
```

This will work since local space should be the same for `B` and `D`, because locally when parented to `A` and `C`they both start on `Vector3.zero`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Comment: just to update, in your solution should it be D instead of C in the code? Because when I use D instead of C, it works.

Comment: You were totally right, I misplaced it, I have edited it